# How do I convert an NSNumber to NSData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdata, gamekit

I need to transmit an integer through GameKit using `sendDataToAllPeers:withDataMode:error:` but I don't know how to convert my NSNumber to NSData in order to send. I currently have:

```
NSNumber *indexNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
[gkSession sendDataToAllPeers:indexNum withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
```

but obviously the indexNum needs to be converted to NSData before I can send it. Does anyone know how to do this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I would not recommend `NSKeyedArchiver` for such a simple task, because it adds PLIST overhead on top of it and class versioning.

Pack:

```
NSUInteger index = <some number>;
NSData *payload = [NSData dataWithBytes:&index length:sizeof(index)];
```

Send:

```
[session sendDataToAllPeers:payload withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
```

Unpack (in the GKSession receive handler):

```
NSUInteger index;
[payload getBytes:&index length:sizeof(index)];
```

#### Swift

```
var i = 123
let data = NSData(bytes: &i, length: sizeof(i.dynamicType))

var i2 = 0
data.getBytes(&i2, length: sizeof(i2.dynamicType))

print(i2) // "123"
```

Comment: You assume that the number is a NSUInteger while unpacking. NSNumber can wrap whole lot of different type of numbers - int, float, double, signed / unsigned. I think that archiving and unarchiving is best approach if programmer is not sure what type of data is stored in NSNumber. I go with Ole's approach.

Comment: Where do you see NSNumber? I never use NSNumber.

Comment: The question asked was for NSNumber created from an integer. So, I guess a general solution for NSNumber would have been more appropriate.

Comment: @Erik Aigner: do you know how to solve this problem with Swift? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22):

To store it:

```
NSData *numberAsData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:indexNum];
```

To convert it back to NSNumber:

```
NSNumber *indexNum = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:numberAsData];
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it doesn't assume the number is an integer.

Comment: @TTillage Number doesn't have to be an integer for my solution to work. You just have to change the type.

Comment: The answer perfectly matches the title of the question. However @ErikAigner's answer is more specific towards the body of the question.

Answer (score 4):

Why not send the integer directly like this:

```
NSData * indexData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&index length:sizeof(index)];
[gkSession sendDataToAllPeers:indexData withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more detailed example how to send different payloads you can check the GKRocket example included in the XCode documentation.