# How to build NSData from decimal value?

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nsdata

I have a decimal value (read from BLE device with GATT) `256` (the same app also displays this value as `0x00010000` and indicate type as `16BIT FLOAT`). Here is [the description](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.hid_information.xml) of the data structure.

How should I generate the same value as `NSData`?

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689689/how-do-i-convert-an-nsnumber-to-nsdata

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code so we can see what you have.

Comment: @rmaddy, here is another question with the code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121617/how-to-properly-reply-on-ble-didreceivereadrequest-for-hid-hid-information (since Joze already replied on the original question).

Comment: Don't post a new question. Delete that one and update this one.

Comment: @rmaddy, this question is answered (and answered fully). Now I recognized that I should find answer for another question. They are related to the same task, but they are different. So, I think both questions should exist.

Comment: If this question is answered then mark it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this since in the end it is a float value.

Encoding:

```
NSMutableData * data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
[data appendBytes:&yourfloatvalue length:sizeof(float)];
```

Decoding:

```
NSData * data = ...; // loaded from bluetooth
float yourfloatvalue;
[data getBytes:&yourfloatvalue length:sizeof(float)];
```

If you don't want to use NSMutableData then you can do this:

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&yourfloatvalue length:sizeof(float)];
```